Constraining coroutine_traits for ClassType while supporting lambdas
I'm currently writing a coroutine/promise library that works with co_await, and I'm having difficulty constraining coroutine_traits for member functions when there are unrelated lambdas returning the task type.
An example that reproduces the issue on Godbolt:
#include <type_traits>
#include <coroutine>
#include <future>

template<typename T>
class TaskType {
};

class SomeSafeClassA {};
class SomeSafeClassB {};

template<typename T>
concept IsSafeClassA = std::is_base_of_v<SomeSafeClassA, T>;
template<typename T>
concept IsSafeClassB = std::is_base_of_v<SomeSafeClassB, T>;

namespace std {

template<typename... Args>
struct coroutine_traits<TaskType<int>, Args...>{
    using promise_type = TaskType<int>;
};

template<IsSafeClassA ClassType, typename... Args>
struct coroutine_traits<TaskType<int>, ClassType&, Args...>{
    using promise_type = TaskType<int>;
};

template<IsSafeClassB ClassType, typename... Args>
struct coroutine_traits<TaskType<int>, ClassType&, Args...>{
    using promise_type = TaskType<int>;
};

}

int main()
{
    auto k = []() -> TaskType<int> {
        co_return 6;
    };
}

Now obviously the TaskType isn't fully implemented here (it is in the real version). The issue is this compilation error:
.../type_traits:3514:60: error: incomplete type 'const (lambda at <source>:38:14)' used in type trait expression
 3514 |   inline constexpr bool is_base_of_v = __is_base_of(_Base, _Derived);
      |                                                            ^
<source>:13:29: note: in instantiation of variable template specialization 'std::is_base_of_v<SomeSafeClassA, const (lambda at <source>:38:14)>' requested here
   13 | concept IsSafeClassA = std::is_base_of_v<SomeSafeClassA, T>;

Now the lambda - if it were a complete type - would fail the is_base_of test anyway. What I want is for lambdas to match the first template specialization; this one:
template<typename... Args>
struct coroutine_traits<TaskType<int>, Args...>{
    using promise_type = TaskType<int>;
};

without throwing a compiler error due to an incomplete type on the class-based specializations. Those specializations are intended for member functions, aren't relevant for lambdas at all, and should not be evaluated (or at least evaluated and fail to match, rather than causing a compilation error).
How can I define the class-based coroutine_traits specializations without lambdas causing compiler errors?

What I've done for now is add a more-specific specialization of the task type that lambdas can return, e.g.
template <typename ResultType> class TLambdaTask : public TTask<ResultType>
{
public:
    // ... pass through any constructors down to TTask
};

Then I can define a specialization for this lambda-specific type:
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct coroutine_traits<TLambdaTask<ReturnType>, Args...>
{
    // using promise_type = ...
};

Any lambdas that use co_await can then return this lambda-specific type, which can only match against the TLambdaTask specializations (and not the class specializations for TTask generally):
auto k = []() -> TLambdaTask<int> {
    co_return 6;
};

Still, if anyone has a way of making this work without a derived TLambdaTask type, that would be far more ideal.
